# Travis CI cannot resolve JavaScript module by importing folder that contains index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, travis-ci

I have the following code inside `src/index.js`

```
import Dialpad from './components/dialpad';

// ...
```

Directory `src/components/dialpad/Index.js` contains the definition of the React component, dialpad, as follows:

```
class Dialpad extends Component {
   // ...
}

export default Dialpad;
```

I can successfully build my bundle using Webpack on my local machine. However, it fails on Travis CI:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/dialpad' in '/home/travis/build/mhmtztmr/react-dialpad/src'
 @ ./src/index.js 2:16-44
```

Once I replace `import Dialpad from './components/dialpad'` to `import Dialpad from './components/dialpad/Index'` it works fine on Travis CI as well.

I don't want to append `Index` to the imports in case I have the chance not to do it and utilize that module resolution convention. Why is Travis CI unable to resolve modules imported via folder name while I can on my local machine? `.travis.yml` is quite simple:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "stable"
```

Should I add some config to `.travis.yml` for the proper module resolution?